# Symfony choice type array error: Unable to transform value for property path: Expected an array

Tags: php, symfony

Why am I getting an error with this form choice set to multiple. This is coming directly off of Symfonys website. All I changed was the variable name.

```
 $builder->add('genre', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => array(
        'x'   => 'x',
        'y' => 'y',
        'z'   => 'z',
    ),
    'multiple' => true,
));
```

This is the error:

> Unable to transform value for property path "genre": Expected an array.

Here is my entity class for this variable:

```
 /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="genre", type="text", nullable=true)
 */
private $genre;
```

Comment: With multiple choices being available the form will create an `array` of results but your "genre" property is only a `string`. You will either need to change the mapping for genre to an `array` or remove the `'multiple' => true`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback

Comment: Did you get it to work?

Comment: 'mapped' => false makes it work

Comment: $builder->get('genre')->resetViewTransformers(); and works with me

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that the comment by qooplmao solves the issue:

The problem is that your entity field `$genre` is not defied as an `array` but as a `string`.

But when multiple choices are enabled, the form field will provide an `array` as a result, and not a string.

So you can:

- map `genre` as an `array` instead of a `string`
- or disable multiple choices by setting `multiple` to false

I this specific problem I guess that you want to map `genre` as an `array`.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for bypass error, juste use this code.

```
explode("|",$response['quest1'])
```

use explode for solve you problème

Im use | separatore you can replace | by ,

example code in under

```
 $builder->add('genre', 'choice', array(
'choices' => array(
    'x'   => 'x',
    'y' => 'y',
    'z'   => 'z',
),
  'multiple' => true,
   explode("|",$response['genre']),
));
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem with 'data' option

```
    ->add('flags', ChoiceType::class, [
        'choices' => [Agent::FLAGS],
        'expanded' => true,
        'multiple' => true,
        'required' => false,
        'data' => Agent::FLAGS,
    ])
```

i am use a bitwise flags, so the database type is a int, and the screen info is a checkbox with a lot of checkboxes.

using the 'data' i can say to symfony what type of data i will use and everthing works.

Answer (score 0):

public function getGenre(): **array** {
...

Answer (score 0):

Just add data  array (empty array if you don't expect any checkbox to be selected by default, or all the values you want to be selected by default )`''multiple' => true, data'=>['']`